# Using PostgreSQL and Nodejs, How Do I Have My Function Return A Query?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to backend development, and am learning about the basics, so don't worry too much about my code quality.

Basically, I'm trying to learn how, if you wanted to wrap your queries in a layer of abstraction, how you would wrap specific queries into a function that returns the data from the query. For instance, in this function,

```
  async retrieveUserOfCompany(companyName) {
    this.client.connect()
    await this.client.query("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE compname = '" + companyName + "';", (err, res) => {
      return res.rows;
      this.client.end()
    });
  }
```

I'm returning some data from a company. However, when I call the function, I get that the query returned undefined. How would I go about fixing this? I've worked out that its because the db call is async, so I've tried incorporating async and await into the function, but I don't believe I quite have it right.

Comment: Do not pass a callback to `query` when you want to work with promises (and `await`).

Comment: Like in your previous question, this still has a SQL injection security problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code isn't complete, but it looks like `retrieveUserOfCompany` is a class method, and `client` is a class property.  Assuming that's true, your function could be written like so:

```
async retrieveUserOfCompany(companyName) {
    try {
        // wait for connection
        const client = await this.client.connect()
        // wait for query response
        const resp = await client.query("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE compname = '" + companyName + "';");
        return resp.rows;
    } catch(err) {
        throw(err);
    } finally {
        this.client.end();
    }
}
```

Async functions return a promise, which you will eventually need to unwrap.  Assuming that `retrieveUserOfCompany` is a method on `MyDbClass`, and you have defined an instance of that called `myDb`, you could get your rows like this:

```
myDbInstance.retrieveUserOfCompany("Foo Company")
    .then(rows => console.log(rows))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Thanks @bergi for pointing out `client.end()` should be in `finally` clause to ensure the connection is closed.

Comment: The `end` call really should be in a `finally` clause.